# How to add file upload option to Magento2 contact form?

Tags: magento2, file-upload, contact-form

I want to give users option to upload a file in magento2 contact form and recieve it in the email as attachment. How to do that? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

`upload` field in contact form and include it in contact **email template**.

[This](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-upload-field-in-contact-form-and-send-as-attachment/) will help you to achieve

Comment: The link you posted is about Magento 1

Answer (score 0):

You can Refer below link and create a module:-
https://github.com/vijayrami/Magelearn_ContactAttachment
Thanks